# Error: CS1503 Argument 1 and Error:CS0019 '=='

Tags: c#, string, arguments, decimal

We are currently learning about functions, parameters, arguments in a class, so I want to keep the same format since 'decimal price' and 'decimal amount' will be inputed into a function definition

I have tried different ways to turn the 'decimal' into a 'string' to be able to prevent the user from entering characters instead of a decimal, but I don't know why it isn't working

Since 'amount' is a `decimal`, it needs to be converted into a `string` to be able to run `(amount == string.Empty)`, but as the first problem I cannot figure it out.

```
        decimal price; 
        decimal amount; 



        Console.Write("What is the price?"); 
        price = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 


        double pricenumber;

        while (!double.TryParse(price, out pricenumber)) //error here 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You've not entered a price.\r\nPlease enter a price");
            price = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        Console.Write("How many were you planning on purchasing?"); 

        amount = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

        while (amount == string.Empty) //error here
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You cannot leave this blank.\r\nPlease enter how many are needed:");
            amount = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Comment: You may want to read on https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+numeric+type+conversion ...

Answer (score 2):

There are some logical flaws in your code, which you'll have to fix. Please see the comments:

```
Console.Write("What is the price?"); 
price = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // you're already parsing the user-input into
// a decimal. This is somewhat problematic, because if the user enters "foo" instead 
// of "123" the attempt to parse the input will fail

double pricenumber;
while (!double.TryParse(price, out pricenumber)) // the variable "price" already contains
// a parsed decimal. That's what you did some lines above. "TryParse" expects a string to
// be parsed whereas you're committing the parsed decimal
{
    Console.WriteLine("You've not entered a price.\r\nPlease enter a price");
    price = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

So what you should do instead is keeping the user-input as a string until you're then trying to parse it:

```
Console.Write("What is the price?"); 
string input = Console.ReadLine(); // keep as string

double pricenumber;
while (!decimal.TryParse(input, out pricenumber))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You've not entered a price.\r\nPlease enter a price");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

The same goes for your other attempt. Again, please look at the comments:

```
Console.Write("How many were you planning on purchasing?"); 
amount = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // you're already parsing the string into a
// decimal

while (amount == string.Empty) // as you can't compare a decimal with a string, this 
// creates an error
{
    Console.WriteLine("You cannot leave this blank.\r\nPlease enter how many are needed:");
    amount = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

You could solve it the same way as above:

```
Console.Write("How many were you planning on purchasing?"); 
input = Console.ReadLine(); // again, keep as string

while (!decimal.TryParse(input, out amount))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You cannot leave this blank.\r\nPlease enter how many are needed:");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

If there's room for further optimization you could and should put that logic into a separate method as the code is nearly identically and would lead to duplicates.

```
private static decimal GetParsedInput(string question, string noticeOnFailed)
{
    Console.Write(question); 
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    decimal result;
    while (!decimal.TryParse(input, out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(questionOnFailed);
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
decimal price = GetParsedInput(
    "What is the price?", 
    "You've not entered a price.\r\nPlease enter a price:");
decimal amount = GetParsedInput(
    "How many were you planning on purchasing?", 
    "You cannot leave this blank.\r\nPlease enter how many are needed:");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string price;
        string amount;



        Console.Write("What is the price?");
        price = Console.ReadLine();


        double pricenumber;

        while (!double.TryParse(price, out pricenumber)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You've not entered a price.\r\nPlease enter a price");
            price = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        Console.Write("How many were you planning on purchasing?");

        double amountnumber;
        amount = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!double.TryParse(amount, out amountnumber)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You cannot leave this blank.\r\nPlease enter how many are needed:");
            amount = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I figured it out
>
> I've done this instead

```
{ public static decimal questions(string question)
    {
        Console.Write(question);
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
       
        decimal result;
        while (!decimal.TryParse(answer, out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(question);
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return result;
}
```

> Usage:

```
 string productcost = "How much does one " + productname + " cost? ";
 questions(productcost);
```

> worked perfectly